I can't exit from Tux of Math Command
I can't exit from the "Tux of Math Command" game.
There is a cross at the upper right corner, but it doesn't work. I clicked on it, but there are no movements.

It seems that the "Tux of Math Command" game is hung. Open the System Monitor application, look for the tux-math process, and note its 4-digit or 5-digit ID number. Then run the following command to close "Tux of Math Command":
kill 4-or-5-digit-ID-number

Replace 4-or-5-digit-ID-number in the above command with the ID number that you noted in the System Monitor.
